# JMeter running multiple server in non gui mode

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I am using jmeter in Non GUI mode. I have set up the distributed environment with 15 servers. Now I want to run 2 test at a time. With each tests on different set of servers.

Test1  : server1, server2
Test3  : server3, server4,server5

Below is the command I used:
./jmeter -n -t pathtojmx -R server1,server2

But this shows below error:
An error occurred: Unknown arg: server2
errorlevel=1

I can run the same command after removing server2.

Jmeter version: 2.13
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters with commas need to be quoted:

```
./jmeter -n -t pathtojmx -R "server1,server2"
```

Otherwise they are considered separate arguments.